# Pandas data reader update, getting FRED currency exchange rates

Tags: python, pandas, datareader

So, I was attempting to grab USD/CNY rates from FRED using Pandas with the following code I found on another stack exchange post:

```
import pandas.io.data as web
cny = wb.get_data_fred('DEXCHUS')
```

However I got an error-

```
ImportError: The pandas.io.data module is moved to a separate package (pandas-datareader). After installing the pandas-datareader package (https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader), you can change the import ``from pandas.io import data, wb`` to ``from pandas_datareader import data, wb``.
```

I followed the GitHub instructions to install pandas-datareader and then changed to `from pandas.io import data, wb` then when I try to run my code I get an error that the module has no `get_data_fred`.

How can I use the updated package to get the FRED data?

Comment: ... did you read the error message and do what it said?

Comment: ....@Solaxun did you read my question? I installed pandas-datareader but am still getting an error.

Comment: Are you now importing from the new package? As the error says, your import should now be `from pandas_datareader import data, wb`

Comment: I read the question, but i didn't see an updated import statement which is what the error message said to do *after* downloading.

Comment: Yes I changed the import statement

Answer (score 3):

There are a few different ways to get the FRED data. For the generic `DataReader` call, try (using version 0.5.0):

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
cny = pdr.DataReader("DEXCHUS", "fred")
```

Or, more similar to the syntax you had previously:

```
from pandas_datareader import data
cny = data.get_data_fred("DEXCHUS")
```

The `data.get_data_fred` method just returns the following, which provides a third way to get your data:

```
# Connect to FRED report and read from connection
cny = data.FredReader("DEXCHUS").read()
```

All results should be identical, however I prefer the more general first call myself.